# Cron Job and permissions

Tags: permissions, cron

I have set a cron job to execute a bash script. If I change the permissions of the script to (Others: None) will it still be executed?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Who wants to run the script? If 'root', yes there is no problem, otherwise the runner should have group or owner execution permission.
If you just put your script into cron.* folders, it is run by root. But you might use `crontab -e`.

Comment: Its a backup job thats runs every day when I am logged in.